# Cannot use for loop in R for gsub

Tags: r, for-loop, gsub

I want to pass my elements from the Country_input vector into my for loop however the gsub keeps printing NaN as the output.

```
Revenue <- read.csv("Revenue.csv")

Traffic <- read.csv("Traffic.csv")

Country_input <- c("CH", "CZ", "DE", "FR", "NL", "PL", "UK")


RPS_country <- sum(Revenue[Revenue$Country == "x" & Revenue$Week =="2016-11", "Revenue"]) / sum(Traffic[Traffic$Country == "x" & Traffic$Week =="2016-11", "Sessions"])


output <- NULL
for (i in 1:length(Country_input)){
  output[i] <-gsub("x", Country_input[i], RPS_country)
}
```

Unfortunately, whenever I run this, the `gsub` always returns a NaN as output.

```
> output
[1] NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    "NaN"
```

Comment: `for (i in 1:length(Country_input))`. `length(Country_input)` is a single value.

Comment: another thing is `RPS_country` is a numeric value. Just one numeric value obtained from summing. Therefore it does not contain `x`. But this is not the reason it is giving you `NA`

Comment: Hi LAP i have amended to for i in 1:length However, it will still producing an output: [1] "NaN" "NaN" "NaN" "NaN" "NaN" "NaN" "NaN"

Comment: @Onyambu Thanks Onyambu, how do I solve this? Any idea how I can change RPS_country and make it different?

Comment: You need to give us an example of your data. If  you can, post the output from `dput` (for all your data or the first rows), please.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys! I think Onyambu helped me get to the answer. As RPS_Country outputs a single numeric value. I couldn't pass through my for loop to a single value.

I have thus decided to create vectors separately and sum them out AFTER the loop as such:

```
x <- NULL
y <- NULL
for (i in 1:length(Country_input)){
  x[i] <- sum(Revenue[Revenue$Country == Country_input[i] & Revenue$Week =="2016-11","Revenue"])
  y[i] <- sum(Traffic[Traffic$Country == Country_input[i] & Traffic$Week =="2016-11","Sessions"])
  }
RPS_Country <- round(x/y, 3)
RPS_Country
```